# Using node.js to proxy http and websocket traffic

Tags: node.js, websocket, reverse-proxy, atmosphere, node-http-proxy

I'm expanding on a node.js reverse proxy I put together with mikeal's request module: https://github.com/mikeal/request . It is a connect app that uses a small piece of custom middleware to check if the the current request is for an API route and if so it proxies it to and from a different API server like this:

```
  .use(function(req, res, next){
    if( /^\/api\//.test(req.url) ){  
      req.pipe(request(apiUrl + req.url))
        .on('error', function(err){
          handlePipeError(err, 'Error piping request to proxy server. Details: ');
        })
        .pipe(res)
        .on('error', function(err){
          handlePipeError(err, 'Error piping proxy response to client. Details: ')
        });


      function handlePipeError(err, customMsg) {
        console.log( customMsg, err );

        res.writeHead(503, {
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(err.message, 'utf8'),
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end(err.message);
      }
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
```

There is also some other middleware to handle static file serving and some other stuff. Once all the middleware is setup I start the server like this:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(port)
```

I would now like to expand this script to allow reverse proxying websocket connections. I tried using the nodejitsu/node-http-proxy to do modify the previous portion of the code like so:

```
var options = {
  ws: true,
  target: apiUrl,
  secure: false,
  xfwd: true
};
var wsProxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer(options);

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  console.log("--- CAUGHT UPGRADE ----");
  wsProxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});

server.listen(port);
```

I notice the upgrade event fires off and the callback function does run but the websockets request isn't actually working (the client seems to never establish a connection). Is there a better way to achieve this

Comment: Hi @novon did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue